# Row-wise scan through a polars LazyFrame

Tags: rust-polars

I have a TSV file that is larger than my memory. I want to use the `polars` crate in the Rust programming language to iterate over this TSV file and benefit from polars' capabilities such as parsing.

Is this possible with the `LazyFrame` API?

Comment: LazyCsvReader with tab delimiter? https://docs.rs/polars/latest/polars/prelude/struct.LazyCsvReader.html#method.with_delimiter